# Style Table border only on table column in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

Given the following table html, I would like to style my table to have only border around table, and border across column excluding border across rows.

Here is what I already have:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:30%">
        <p>The right-hand thumb "C"</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%">
        <p>Right-handed thumb "B"</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%">
        <p>Representatives of "A"</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>You pay the mortgage</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Borrower (Please note: we have actually received the correct merchandise from the supplier)</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Signature and stamp</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Name ..................... ..</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Seang Chhay and Song Heng</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As here is I tried to accomplish is like below:

[image: Table have border only across column]

Which bootstrap style and CSS style I could add to archive above result? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `border-top` and `border-bottom` of all `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<td>` elements. You should also use a additional class to change only the choosen tables.

```css
.only-table-and-columns td,
.only-table-and-columns th,
.only-table-and-columns tr,
.only-table-and-columns thead,
.only-table-and-columns tbody {
  border-bottom:0 !important;
  border-top:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table-bordered only-table-and-columns">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:30%">
        <p>The right-hand thumb "C"</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%">
        <p>Right-handed thumb "B"</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%">
        <p>Representatives of "A"</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>You pay the mortgage</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Borrower (Please note: we have actually received the correct merchandise from the supplier)</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Signature and stamp</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Name ..................... ..</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Seang Chhay and Song Heng</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**This also works with Bootstrap 4:**

```css
.only-table-and-columns td,
.only-table-and-columns th,
.only-table-and-columns tr,
.only-table-and-columns thead,
.only-table-and-columns tbody {
  border-bottom:0 !important;
  border-top:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table-bordered only-table-and-columns">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:30%">
        <p>The right-hand thumb "C"</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%">
        <p>Right-handed thumb "B"</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%">
        <p>Representatives of "A"</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>You pay the mortgage</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Borrower (Please note: we have actually received the correct merchandise from the supplier)</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Signature and stamp</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Name ..................... ..</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Seang Chhay and Song Heng</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use div which is much easier to understand

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <div class="container-fluid padding-0">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm" style="border:1px solid black">
                        The right-hand thumb "C"
                        You pay the mortgage
                        Name ..................... ..
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm" style="border:1px solid black">

                  Right-handed thumb "B"
                  Borrower (Please note: we have actually received the correct merchandise from the supplier)

                  Seang Chhay and Song Heng
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm" style="border:1px solid black">
                        Representatives of "A"
                        Signature and stamp
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```